# Solving equation with constraints

Tags: equation-solving, constraint

Given the following set of equations:

```
vEq = v == Pi (L R^2 + 1/12 L^3 Tan[Alpha]^2)
oEq = o == 1/2 Pi (4 R (L + R) + L^2 Tan[Alpha]^2)
```

I can solve this with `Solve` if for `L` and `R` when I give the following constraints

```
constraints = 0 <= Tan[Alpha]^2 <= (4 R^2)/L^2 && R > 0 && L > 0 && v > 0 && o > 0
```

But when I try to solve it with

```
constraints = -ArcTan[(2 R)/L] <= Alpha <= ArcTan[(2 R)/L] && R > 0 && L > 0 && v > 0 && o > 0
```

`Solve` refuses to solve the equation. Why is that? In my case the second formulation would be better, because it restrains `Alpha` to exactly one interval and not many.

The call for `Solve` reads

```
Solve[oEq && vEq && constraints, {L, R}]
```

Comment: I think you should use any constraints for `Simplify`, rather than for Solve. Further, for me Mma solved your equations without any constraints. The solution is cumbersome, but this is another story. It is as cumbersome as it is. Nothing could be done.

Comment: You only give constraints concerning Alpha. What about v and o?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results! Only with the reduced constraints R>0&&L>0  MMA gives a result (containing Root...).

Comment: If you try to eliminate R by hand using the first equation(assuming L>0) you'll get `{R -> 1/2 Sqrt[(4 v)/(L \[Pi]) - 1/3 L^2 Tan[Alpha]^2]}`. Because R>0 this result  gives you an additional constraint `L^3 < (12 v)/(Pi Tan[Alpha]^2)` ...

Comment: `v` and `o` are also greater than zero. I'll edit it in the question

Comment: and you are right, at the end I get conditional expressions containing conditions on `o`, `v` and `Alpha`. The question is more why MMA Solves this equation with the constraints on `Alpha` stated in the first formulation and does not given the second formulation. They are equivalent in the region of interest.

Comment: ...they are only equivalent if you restrict Alpha<Pi/2

Comment: well |Alpha| < Pi / 2, but thats my region of interest.

Answer (score 4):

This can be reduced to quite simple form.

Since Tan[Alpha]^2 is periodic, you only need to regard -Pi/2 < Alpha < Pi/2. For simplicity I excluded +-Pi/2.

v and o are totaly positive for that given conditions.

```
Reduce[ForAll[{R, L, Alpha}, R >= 0 && L >= 0 && -Pi/2 < Alpha < Pi/2,
    Pi (L R^2 + 1/12 L^3 Tan[Alpha]^2) >= 0]]

(*    True    *)

Reduce[ForAll[{R, L, Alpha}, R >= 0 && L >= 0 && -Pi/2 < Alpha < Pi/2,
    1/2 Pi (4 R (L + R) + L^2 Tan[Alpha]^2) >= 0]]

(*    True    *)
```

That means, you only have to satisfy the remaining condition

```
Assuming[R > 0 && L > 0 && -Pi/2 < Alpha < Pi/2, 
   FullSimplify[Reduce[Tan[Alpha]^2 <= (4 R^2)/L^2, {R, L}]]]

(*    Tan[Alpha] == 0 || L <= 2 R Sqrt[Cot[Alpha]^2]    *)
```

Graph it to see where conditions are satisfied.

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[{Pi (L R^2 + 1/12 L^3 Tan[Alpha]^2), 
     1/2 Pi (4 R (L + R) + L^2 Tan[Alpha]^2), -Tan[Alpha]^2 + (4 R^2)/
     L^2, 2 R Sqrt[Cot[Alpha]^2] - L}, {Alpha, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue, Red, Cyan}], {{L, 1}, 0, 10}, {{R, 1}, 0,
```

9}]

[image]

Comment: Thats my point. Why doesn't Mathematica simplify `Sqrt[Cot[Alpha]^2` to `1/Tan[Alpha]` ?

Answer (score 1):

The following works in version 11.2.

```
vEq = v == Pi (L R^2 + 1/12 L^3 Tan[Alpha]^2);
oEq = o == 1/2 Pi (4 R (L + R) + L^2 Tan[Alpha]^2);
constraints = -ArcTan[(2 R)/L] <= Alpha <= ArcTan[(2 R)/L] && R > 0 &&
L > 0 && v > 0 && o > 0;
Reduce[{vEq, oEq}, {L, R}]
```

The huge output is omitted.

Addition. Many thanks from me to Ulrich Neumann for his valuable comment. The line

```
FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> constraints]
```

should be added to my code. The long output is

> (Tan[Alpha] != 
>       0 && (L == 
>         Root[36 v^2 - 36 o v #1 + 9 o^2 #1^2 - 
>            6 o [Pi] #1^4 Tan[
>              Alpha]^2 + #1^3 (-36 [Pi] v + 
>               12 [Pi] v Tan[Alpha]^2) + #1^6 (3 [Pi]^2 Tan[
>                 Alpha]^2 + [Pi]^2 Tan[Alpha]^4) &, 1] || 
>        L == Root[
>          36 v^2 - 36 o v #1 + 9 o^2 #1^2 - 
>            6 o [Pi] #1^4 Tan[
>              Alpha]^2 + #1^3 (-36 [Pi] v + 
>               12 [Pi] v Tan[Alpha]^2) + #1^6 (3 [Pi]^2 Tan[
>                 Alpha]^2 + [Pi]^2 Tan[Alpha]^4) &, 2] || 
>        L == Root[
>          36 v^2 - 36 o v #1 + 9 o^2 #1^2 - 
>            6 o [Pi] #1^4 Tan[
>              Alpha]^2 + #1^3 (-36 [Pi] v + 
>               12 [Pi] v Tan[Alpha]^2) + #1^6 (3 [Pi]^2 Tan[
>                 Alpha]^2 + [Pi]^2 Tan[Alpha]^4) &, 3] || 
>        L == Root[
>          36 v^2 - 36 o v #1 + 9 o^2 #1^2 - 
>            6 o [Pi] #1^4 Tan[
>              Alpha]^2 + #1^3 (-36 [Pi] v + 
>               12 [Pi] v Tan[Alpha]^2) + #1^6 (3 [Pi]^2 Tan[
>                 Alpha]^2 + [Pi]^2 Tan[Alpha]^4) &, 4] || 
>        L == Root[
>          36 v^2 - 36 o v #1 + 9 o^2 #1^2 - 
>            6 o [Pi] #1^4 Tan[
>              Alpha]^2 + #1^3 (-36 [Pi] v + 
>               12 [Pi] v Tan[Alpha]^2) + #1^6 (3 [Pi]^2 Tan[
>                 Alpha]^2 + [Pi]^2 Tan[Alpha]^4) &, 5] || 
>        L == 
>         Root[36 v^2 - 36 o v #1 + 9 o^2 #1^2 - 
>            6 o [Pi] #1^4 Tan[
>              Alpha]^2 + #1^3 (-36 [Pi] v + 
>               12 [Pi] v Tan[Alpha]^2) + #1^6 (3 [Pi]^2 Tan[
>                 Alpha]^2 + [Pi]^2 Tan[Alpha]^4) &, 6]) && 
>      6 L^2 [Pi] R + 6 v + L^3 [Pi] Tan[Alpha]^2 == 
>       3 L o) || (Tan[Alpha] == 
>       0 && (L == 
>         Root[-4 v^2 + 4 o v #1 - o^2 #1^2 + 4 [Pi] v #1^3 &, 1] || 
>        L == Root[-4 v^2 + 4 o v #1 - o^2 #1^2 + 4 [Pi] v #1^3 &, 2] || 
>        L == Root[-4 v^2 + 4 o v #1 - o^2 #1^2 + 4 [Pi] v #1^3 &, 3]) &&
>       2 (L^2 [Pi] R + v) == L o)

Comment: ...the constraints aren't involved!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simpler to see this problem with a Replace for the constraint.

```
Solve[{oEq, vEq} //. (Tan[Alpha]^2) -> a (4 R^2)/L^2, {R, L}]
```

where the variable "a" goes from zero to one in the answer. This expression is equivalent with Tan[Alpha]^2 going from 0 to (4 R^2)/L^2. This is called a change of variable.  Mathematica can do so much but you have to simplify the problem at the start.

As for the second constraint, it introduces a negative branch which is removed in the expression of v and o when squared.  I suggest a Replace:

```
Solve[{oEq, vEq} //. (Alpha ->  + ArcTan[(2 R)/L]), {R, L}]
Solve[{oEq, vEq} //. (Alpha ->  - ArcTan[(2 R)/L]), {R, L}]
```

which give, from what I can see, the same solutions. I suggest the introduction of the same variable "a" which varies from 0 to 1 in the final answer.

```
Solve[{oEq, vEq} //. (Alpha ->  + ArcTan[ Sqrt[a] (2 R)/L]), {R, L}]
```

Only then can you see the two constraints give the same solutions. You get a real solution and a set of imaginary solutions for R and L which have to be discarded  (I presume!).

Comment: Looking at the given equation, Alpha seems to be a parameter, which doesn't depend on the variables R,L !!! So your substitution  is not ok.